# Problems with Type 1 fonts for arrows in XY package

Tags: dvips

I have just installed Basic MikTeX (basic-miktex-22.10-x64.exe just downloaded from miktex.org).

I am trying to run the simple toy example of XY diagram using the following file (named test.tex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}

$$
\xymatrix{
\mathbf{H}
\ar@/^/[rr]^-{ } \ar@/_/[dr]_-{ }
&&
\mathbf{H} \ar@/^/[dl]^-{ } \ar@/^/[ll]^-{ }
\\
& \mathbf{H} \ar@/^/[ur] \ar@/_/[ul]
}
$$

\end{document}
```

XY package has beens installed automatically, so latex test.tex runs OK.

After this I run dvips test.dvi. According to the output of dvips programme all fonts loaded are Type 1 (with extension *.pfb), incuding those used for arrows:

```
This is dvips(k) 2022.1 (MiKTeX22.12)  Copyright 2022 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2023.01.18:1845' -> test.ps
<F:/MiKTeX29/dvips/base/tex.pro>
<F:/MiKTeX29/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
<F:/MiKTeX29/dvips/base/texps.pro><F:/MiKTeX29/dvips/base/special.pro>.
<F:/MiKTeX29/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
<F:/MiKTeX29/fonts/type1/public/xypic/xybtip10.pfb>
<F:/MiKTeX29/fonts/type1/public/xypic/xyatip10.pfb>
<F:/MiKTeX29/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb>[1]
```

But if I load this test.ps file into Ghostview I see the arrows made not by Type 1 but by Type 3 fonts, with many small "stairs".

If I then run ps2pdf test.ps to obtain the PDF file, in Acrobat Reader I also see arrows with many small "stairs". At the same time, when I see the "Properties" of this file in Acrobat Reader, all fonts (including XYATIP10 and XYBTIP10 used for arrows) are marked as Type 1 fonts.

Could anybody help me to understand what is going on and why Type 1 fonts look like Type 3 fonts? And how can this problem be solved?

Many thanks.

Comment: the fonts are imho only the arrow tips, the lines are built from lots of small rules. With pdflatex you get a curve.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right: arrow tips are smooth and with pdflatex I get smooth curves. But why I cannot get smooth curves with latex+dvips? Is it possible to get smooth curves with latex+dvips?

Comment: Does `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}` repair the arrow tips? It is generally recommended to use `cmtip` with `xy`.

Comment: Arrow tips are OK, the problem is only with curves.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `dvips` option, that's not loaded by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,dvips]{xy}
\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
\mathbf{H}
  \ar@<0.6ex>@/^/[rr]^-{ } \ar@<-0.6ex>@/_/[dr]_-{ }
&& \mathbf{H}
  \ar@<0.6ex>@/^/[dl]^-{ } \ar@<-0.6ex>@/^/[ll]^-{ }
\\
& \mathbf{H}
  \ar@<-0.6ex>@/^/[ur] \ar@<0.6ex>@/_/[ul]
}
\]

\end{document}
```

I've added `cmtip` for better arrow tips and some amount of sliding in order to avoid overlaps.

[image]

Avoid `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: egreg, many-many thanks! This works! Thank you very much!